# SQL query erroring - need fresh eyes

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

Ok, first, I'm building a query to search MLS data that has been provided in the form of a MySQL database, So I don't have control over the data format, and thus I believe I have to do a lot of casting to get the data in a manageable form. The SQL error is being thown.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your   
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' DECIMAL(2, 1)) / .5, 
CAST(idx1.full_baths, DECIMAL(2, 1))), DECIMAL(2, 1)) AS b' at line 1
```

Looked up the error code and it sends me to a reserved words page, but I can't identify any reserved words.

and now the sql

(all fields are natively `VARCHAR`)

```
SELECT  idx_common.mls_no AS mls_no, 
        CONCAT_WS(" ", idx_common.street_no, idx_common.street_direction, idx_common.street_name) AS address, 
        idx_common.city AS city, 
        idx_common.state AS state, 
        idx_common.total_sqft AS total_sqft, 
        idx_common.asking_price AS price, 
        idx1.bedrooms AS bedrooms, 
        CAST(
            SUM(
                (CAST(idx1.half_baths, DECIMAL(2, 1)) / .5), 
                CAST(idx1.full_bath, DECIMAL(2, 1))
            ), 
            DECIMAL(2, 1)
        ) AS bathrooms, 
        idx1.residential_prop_type AS type, 
        "Listing Agent" AS agent 

FROM (idx_common) 
JOIN idx1 ON idx_common.mls_no = idx1.mls_no 

WHERE `idx_common`.`mls_no` = 'query' 
OR idx_common.zip LIKE '%query%' 
OR idx_common.city LIKE '%query%'
```

Comment: You've got CAST, but use the [parameter format for CONVERT]( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html).  Additionally, an aggregate without a GROUP BY has the potential to return arbitrary results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you don't need `SUM` here at all:

```
SELECT  idx_common.mls_no AS mls_no, 
        CONCAT_WS(" ", idx_common.street_no, idx_common.street_direction, idx_common.street_name) AS address, 
        idx_common.city AS city, 
        idx_common.state AS state, 
        idx_common.total_sqft AS total_sqft, 
        idx_common.asking_price AS price, 
        idx1.bedrooms AS bedrooms, 
        CAST(idx1.half_baths AS DECIMAL(2, 1)) * .5 +
        CAST(idx1.full_bath AS DECIMAL(2, 1)) AS bathrooms, 
        idx1.residential_prop_type AS type, 
        "Listing Agent" AS agent 
FROM    idx_common
JOIN    idx1
ON      idx_common.mls_no = idx1.mls_no 
WHERE   `idx_common`.`mls_no` = 'query' 
        OR idx_common.zip LIKE '%query%' 
        OR idx_common.city LIKE '%query%'
```

I also changed `/ 0.5` to `* 0.5` since it seems to be more appropriate for this query.

If an apartment has `3` half bathrooms and `2` full bathrooms, this query will output `(3 / 2) + 2` = `3.5` bathrooms.

Is it what you wanted?

Answer (score 3):

SUM() takes a single argument.  You have SUM( Cast(...), Cast(...) )

I think you meant to do +, not SUM
  (CAST(idx1.half_baths, DECIMAL(2, 1)) / .5) **+**
   CAST(idx1.full_bath, DECIMAL(2, 1))

SUM adds all values of the column in the whole table.  You can only use it in a GROUP BY query.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that was also a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the function `CAST` works with `AS`, not a `","`. Like this:

```
CAST(idx1.half_baths AS DECIMAL(2, 1))
```

You need to replace that on all your CASTs.

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that your MYSQL version is > 5.0.8.  The DECIMAL type wasn't added to the CAST function until this version.